# C++ code compiles, but when run fails to find library function (1-character difference in function name)

Tags: c++, macos, clang++, dynamic-linking

I'm writing a Python extension module wrapping [a C++ library](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/). In my module I call the function `Rule.set_filter` in the library ([code](https://github.com/larsga/pymapnik3/blob/main/src/pymapnik3.cpp#L1066)), and this compiles, but when I run it it fails with `ImportError: dlopen(/Users/larsga/cvs-co/fhdb/reports/pymapnik3.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace`. This is on MacOS, as you can see.

The symbol that's not found is quite long:

```
__ZN6mapnik4rule10set_filterERKNSt3__110shared_ptrIN6mapbox4util7variantIJNS_10value_nullEbidN6icu_7113UnicodeStringENS_9attributeENS_16global_attributeENS_23geometry_type_attributeENS4_17recursive_wrapperINS_10unary_nodeINS_4tags6negateEEEEENSC_INS_11binary_nodeINSE_4plusEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_5minusEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_4multEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_3divEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_3modEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_4lessEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_10less_equalEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_7greaterEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_13greater_equalEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_8equal_toEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_12not_equal_toEEEEENSC_INSD_INSE_11logical_notEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_11logical_andEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_10logical_orEEEEENSC_INS_16regex_match_nodeEEENSC_INS_18regex_replace_nodeEEENSC_INS_19unary_function_callEEENSC_INS_20binary_function_callEEEEEEEE
```

Demangled:

```
_mapnik::rule::set_filter(std::__1::shared_ptr<mapbox::util::variant<mapnik::value_null, bool, int, double, icu_71::UnicodeString, mapnik::attribute, mapnik::global_attribute, mapnik::geometry_type_attribute, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::unary_node<mapnik::tags::negate> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::plus> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::minus> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::mult> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::div> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::mod> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::less> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::less_equal> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::greater> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::greater_equal> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::equal_to> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::not_equal_to> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::unary_node<mapnik::tags::logical_not> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::logical_and> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::logical_or> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::regex_match_node>, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::regex_replace_node>, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::unary_function_call>, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_function_call> > > const&)
```

When I look at the mapnik dylib I find that a *very* similar function is defined there:

```
__ZN6mapnik4rule10set_filterERKNSt3__110shared_ptrIN6mapbox4util7variantIJNS_10value_nullEbxdN6icu_7113UnicodeStringENS_9attributeENS_16global_attributeENS_23geometry_type_attributeENS4_17recursive_wrapperINS_10unary_nodeINS_4tags6negateEEEEENSC_INS_11binary_nodeINSE_4plusEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_5minusEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_4multEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_3divEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_3modEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_4lessEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_10less_equalEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_7greaterEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_13greater_equalEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_8equal_toEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_12not_equal_toEEEEENSC_INSD_INSE_11logical_notEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_11logical_andEEEEENSC_INSI_INSE_10logical_orEEEEENSC_INS_16regex_match_nodeEEENSC_INS_18regex_replace_nodeEEENSC_INS_19unary_function_callEEENSC_INS_20binary_function_callEEEEEEEE
```

Demangled:

```
_mapnik::rule::set_filter(std::__1::shared_ptr<mapbox::util::variant<mapnik::value_null, bool, long long, double, icu_71::UnicodeString, mapnik::attribute, mapnik::global_attribute, mapnik::geometry_type_attribute, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::unary_node<mapnik::tags::negate> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::plus> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::minus> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::mult> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::div> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::mod> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::less> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::less_equal> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::greater> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::greater_equal> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::equal_to> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::not_equal_to> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::unary_node<mapnik::tags::logical_not> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::logical_and> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_node<mapnik::tags::logical_or> >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::regex_match_node>, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::regex_replace_node>, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::unary_function_call>, mapbox::util::recursive_wrapper<mapnik::binary_function_call> > > const&)
```

It's not the same, though. Character 91 (0-based) is `i` in my code, but `x` in the mapnik library.

The piece that's different is `10value_nullEbidN6icu` in my library and `10value_nullEbxdN6icu` in mapnik. See the `Ebid` vs `Ebxd`.

Now, my question is *why* is there a one-character difference here? Somehow I must be compiling these two codebases slightly differently, but I have no idea how. Mapnik is build with SConsm, while the Python extension is built with distutils.

Mapnik is built with `make`, then installed at `/usr/local/lib/libmapnik.dylib`. The extension module is built with `python3 setup.py build`. I used `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=YES` to verify which mapnik library it's loading.

The compiler used is clang, if that helps.

Comment: `i` stands for `int`, `x` is `long long`. So that's two slightly different signatures.

Comment: Thank you! That helps. The argument to `set_filter` is of type `std::shared_ptr<expr_node>`, and this is [expr_node](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/master/include/mapnik/expression_node_types.hpp#L123). I guess this means `value_integer` or `value_unicode_string` must somehow be differently defined, then. I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: That turned out to be the clue! `value_integer` is 32-bit if `BIGINT` is not defined, and 64-bit if it is. [Code](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/v3.1.x/include/mapnik/value_types.hpp#L47). So mapnik was compiled with `BIGINT`, and I had to set the same. Once I did it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice detective work. Please post that as an answer!

Comment: You might find http://demangler.com/ or the `c++-filt` command useful for solving these problems in the future

Answer (score 1):

Using the tip from @mat that `i` means `int` and `x` means `long long` I was able to figure it out.

The argument to `set_filter` is of type `std::shared_ptr<expr_node>`. ([Code](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/master/include/mapnik/expression_node_types.hpp#L123).) `expr_node` turns out to be a `util::variant` type mixing a whole lot of types. Those are the ones listed in the missing symbol.

The position of the `i`/`x` in the mangled name is pretty close to where `value_integer` appears in the list of alternative types.

Digging further I found that `value_integer` is 32-bit if `BIGINT` is not defined, and 64-bit if it is. ([Code](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/v3.1.x/include/mapnik/value_types.hpp#L47).)

So I figured out that mapnik must have been compiled with `BIGINT`, whereas my module was compiled without. By adding `-DBIGINT` to `extra_compile_args` in my `setup.py` I was able to solve the problem. (Thanks @mat!)